# BroadcastReceiver with AlarmManager and AndroidAnnotations

Tags: broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-annotations

I tried a lot to make this work, but I can't figure out what's wrong. If I call `sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION))`, my broadcast receiver gets called, but it's not working with the AlarmManager:

```
@EReceiver
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends AbstractBroadcastReceiver {

public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
public static final String ACTION = "com.xxx.yyy.alarm";

public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
    Log.e("AUTOMATIC", "setAlarm");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pIntent);
}

@ReceiverAction(ACTION)
public void init(Context context) {
    Log.e("BROADCAST", "woke up receiver action");
    MyService_.intent(context).run().start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the original class in the intent, not the generated one. Change to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver_.class);
```

Note the underscore in the class name.

Comment: OMG! I was sure I had tried that already, but probably when I did it, I made another mistake that covered it.. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the onReceived method in the class that extend BroadcastReceiver

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        // Set the alarm here.
    }
}
```

And also don't forget the permission:

and also add this in your manifest if it's not already done:

```
<receiver android:name="com.theClassThatExtendBroadcastReceiver">
    </receiver>
```

For more information:
http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: What is not needed ?

Comment: Overriding onReceive. That is generated with AndroidAnnotations.